# B2B integration modelling tools and standard suggestions

Tags: modelling

This question might be too broad, but I really need help with this. I am required to choose a standard or notation to model an integration between two business processes, one of which is external.

The question is - are there any standards/notations than can compete with UML Activity Diagram or BPMN. If there are, which should I choose (including the two mentioned)?

Thanks in advance.